# Cannot connect to Jupyter Notebook localhost

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tornado

I have been struggling with this problem the last few days. I am running Manjaro Linux on my laptop and I have recently installed Jupyter Notebook and Jupyterlab using pip.

However, when I try to run it, I get the following output:

```
[I 2021-05-20 16:21:19.980 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2021-05-20 16:21:19.980 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/share/jupyter/lab
[I 16:21:20.005 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/veducha
[I 16:21:20.005 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.0 is running at:
[I 16:21:20.005 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=ffd911982ac39542bc13b182354204b7caec5b86dc5ffad4
[I 16:21:20.005 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=ffd911982ac39542bc13b182354204b7caec5b86dc5ffad4
[I 16:21:20.005 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 16:21:20.056 NotebookApp] 

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///home/veducha/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-72176-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=ffd911982ac39542bc13b182354204b7caec5b86dc5ffad4
 or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=ffd911982ac39542bc13b182354204b7caec5b86dc5ffad4
```

followed by a tab opening on my browser saying that it is unable to connect to the localhost.

I have tried different using browsers, and some of the answers given in other posts (downgrading tornado, for example) do not seem to work since now you're required to have the latest version of tornado.

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks,
E.

Comment: Jupyter works in port 8888 maybe the port is blocked.

Comment: How could I try to unblock it?